# java TimerTask increase time?

Tags: java, timertask

Hi m using the following timer task,and i want to increase the time of this task when a certain condition occurs

```
Timer timer2=new Timer();                   
                timer2.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                    public void run(){

                        //whatevr
                    }
                }, 4000);
```

examlpe

```
if(mycondition)

{
increase time????
}
```

how can i do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract the `TimerTask` in an inner or standalone class. Cancel currently running timer task and schedule a new instance with increased time period.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't**. You'll have to schedule a new task with the incremented period. And if the previous task has become obsolete, make sure that you [`cancel()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel%28%29) it.

---

For future reference, I recommend you utilize the [`Executors`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) framework.

Answer (score 0):

Submit another one task from run() if necessary:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;



public class TimerTaskTest {

private static class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private final Timer timer;
    private boolean fire;

    private MyTimerTask(Timer timer) {
        this(timer, false);
    }

    private MyTimerTask(Timer timer, boolean fire) {
        this.timer = timer;
        this.fire = fire;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!fire) {
            System.out.println(new Date() + " - steady...");
            timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(timer, true), 2000);
        } else {
            System.out.println(new Date() + " - go!");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    MyTimerTask timerTask = new MyTimerTask(timer);

    System.out.println(new Date() + " - ready...");
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 4000);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(7000);
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    }
}

}
```